# GLFW/glfw3.h included failed

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glfw

I just start learning opengl and I started with GLFW library.
And I download the "Windows pre-compiled binaries" from http://www.glfw.org/download.html. Then I unzip my file into C:\GLFW

And now I have a problem when compiling my code. I use mingw in command line, like

> gcc main.c -IC:\GLFW\include\GLFW -LC:\GLFW\lib-mingw -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lgdi32

It always show "fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory"

but if I change `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` into just `#include <glfw3.h>` in my code,

it compiles successfully.

But every tutorial shows me the former. Why?

If I put the header file and lib file into mingw's searching path, is there any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you include directly to `C:\GLFW\include\GLFW`, so there is no `GLFW` folder in this directory. If you want to use `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`, you will want to use this path instead `C:\GLFW\include`.

To answer to your two questions:

1. The include path is very relative to you. What do you prefer, `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` or `#include <glfw3.h>`?
2. You can put the lib and header in the mingw's path, but you have to remember that you will still need to enter the good path (`#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` if you put it in the folder). I would not recommend this method, since I prefer to make an `include` and `lib` folder into my project directory. If you want to do more research: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/includepathhowto.

Comment: Oooooohhhh! I don't know the ' / ' means the directory!!  Sorry for asking such a stupid question..